# How to fake macports into using my build script for ffmpeg?

Tags: macports

I have my own bash script to configure ffmpeg which successfully updates my git repo, builds, tests and installs everything correctly.

Basically I want to bypass macports env and configuration but recognize my build but only for ffmpeg, I don't want macports to look in /usr/local or another location, I want it installed in /opt/local

So it probably boils down to, how to completely disable all the macports env and just launch a subshell with my script?

Created tarball, checksums, etc

```
PortSystem          1.0
PortGroup           muniversal 1.0
name                ffmpeg
epoch               1
version             9.9.9
revision            9
license             LGPL-2.1+
categories          multimedia
maintainers         nomaintainer
platforms           darwin
homepage            http://www.ffmpeg.org/
master_sites       file:///Volumes/Apps_Media/my_repo
use_zip              yes
checksums {they work}
depends_build       port:pkgconfig \
                    port:gmake \
                    port:texinfo
use_configure    no
build.cmd           $HOME/bin/configFFMPEG
```

macports chokes on these lines in ffmpeg's configure

```
FFmpeg/configure: line 3596: ffbuild/config.log: Operation not permitted
FFmpeg/configure: line 3597: ffbuild/config.log: Operation not permitted

echo "# $0 $FFMPEG_CONFIGURATION" > $logfile
set >> $logfile
```

Comment: MacPorts runs builds as the `macports` user, not your normal user or `root`. Make sure that user can both read your script and write to the locations where your script is trying to write.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I run my script as sudo, so I don't see why the permissions weren't inherited and passed to the subshell but this works. If you want, post as answer and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts runs builds as the `macports` user, not yoru normal user or `root`. Make sure that user can both read your script and write to the locations where your script is trying to write.

Even though you invoke MacPorts with superuser privileges, it will not use these privileges while building software.